# JDO - List property ordering

Tags: java, orm, jdo

I am experimenting with JDO against a legacy database schema, and I am trying to understand how to map various scenarios to my objects.

For example say I have an object called "Country" and another called "City", with a 1:N relationship between Country and City, and I have this on the Country object:

```
@Persistent(defaultFetchGroup="true")    
@Element(column="countrycode")
@Order(extensions=@Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="list-ordering", value="name ASC"))    
private List<City> cities;
```

What though if I want to iterate through a list of all countries, and then display their cities in another order - say by population descending?

Am I better *not* to have a "cities" property on the Country object?  And then I can "manually" fetch the cities using a second query which I can then order however I want to?  Or is there another way I'm missing?

Comment: I have no idea which is better but, are you having a specific problem with your code ?

Comment: No it's not a code issue, it's a design question